# How to restore exodus wallet on ubuntu

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum

Is it possible to restore Exodus wallet from email link in ubuntu?
when I click the link it ask to open with xdg-open, but then it does nothing, since its portable and not installed.
Any helps ?

Answer (score 1):

co-founder of Exodus here...

It's not currently possible to restore by just clicking on the link in Ubuntu. However, restoring via the link is still really easy from the developer menu: http://support.exodus.io/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-open-the-developer-menu

The menu to look for is:

`Exodus > Developer > Restore > Restore from recovery link...`

Then paste the link in.